# Nokogiri ignores the entities in the XSL transformation

Tags: ruby, xslt, nokogiri

I try to localize XSLT templates in web application and I want to use entities mechanism for this. But values does not substituted in result document.

Ruby script

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc   = Nokogiri::XML(File.read('test.xml'))
xslt  = Nokogiri::XSLT(File.read('test.xsl'))

puts xslt.transform(doc)
```

XML document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<CommonCard>
  <Test/>
</CommonCard>
```

XSLT stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [
  <!ENTITY labelHello "hello world!">
]>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output encoding="utf-8" method="xml" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    &labelHello; 123
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I want to get this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
hello world! 123
```

But now I get this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 123
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPD**

I use Nokogiri XML engine

Comment: Here is one possible explanation. See last answer: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/849565

Comment: This may well be a vendor-specific parser issue. What is your XSLT engine?

Comment: @Sean B. Durkin - Nokogiri (http://nokogiri.org/)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that this is just a limitation of Nokogiri. I suggest a work-around: use variables instead of entities, like so ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:variable name="labelHello" select="'hello world!'" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="$labelHello" /> 123
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```